# Fatal error using session_start inside foreach (after migration)

Tags: php, session, foreach, infinite-loop

### When did the problem start?

My hosting provider had to change my site to another server like one week ago. Since then, one of my scripts is throwing an error. As everything was working before the changes I'm assuming that the code was initially correct so I'm totally confused why can this happen and I would like you to try getting me in the good direction.

### The code

The code that is giving problems is the following:

```
session_start();
   $items=$_SESSION['items'];
   $_SESSION['numItems']=0;
session_write_close();

foreach($items as $num => $currentItem){

   //here I work with $currentItem...

   session_start();//starting error line
      $_SESSION['numItems']++;
   session_write_close();
}

session_start();
   unset($_SESSION['numItems']);
session_write_close();
```

### The error

If I run the code I get a PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in the line commented as starting error line.

Now, the weirdest thing is that if I check the value of `$_SESSION['numItems']` it can arrive to 12500 (or more) when the array `$items` cannot have more than 250 elements. So something is creating kind of an infinite loop!

### Things to have into account

1. If I comment out the three session lines inside the `foreach` structure (or I move them outside) everything works fine.
2. If I comment out only the second of those lines, the problem persists.
3. The same code structure but with a `while` instead of a `foreach` is working in another script on the same server.
4. My hosting provider cannot say me which PHP version and configuration did I have. Now, the version is 5.2.17.

Thank you for your help!

### Edit:

As it is causing a lot of confusion:

The code structure opens and closes the session because this way I can read the session variables from a second file and have the user updated with the execution progress. This second file is reading `$_SESSION['numItems']` once every 2 seconds and also closes the session with `session_write_close();`.

### Edit 2:

Testing the code but increasing the max execution time with set_time_limit(90) doesn't help at all. It just gives the same error (after waiting longer) and $_SESSION['numItems'] ends with a higher value (around 21000).

Comment: Why are you constantly opening and closing the session? You should only need to use `session_start()` once.

Comment: Let me rephrase this. Why are you writing/closing reopening the session inside of that loop. Why not write/close once after the loop? Get all your data ready first, then start/write/close the session

Comment: Session are I/O. You have to open the session file, deserialize the data into memory. Then you write to the session, and serialize it back to disk. Doing that over and over is going to take some time, though +30s seems extreme. Are you using a custom session implementation, like a remote database? Do you have hundreds of thousands of items to iterate through?

Comment: @MikeW @crush This is because this way while the foreach is running I can read `$_SESSION['numItems']` from another file so the user has real time information of the long execution process. Thank you!

Comment: why you are doing `unset($_SESSION['numItems']);` if you have to unset it than what is the purpose of doing `$_SESSION['numItems']++;`

Comment: @sergold `session_start` and `session_write_close` need an exclusive lock on the file, so, they are waiting in between writes on your other process that is probably endless looping over the session to read it's data.

Comment: @crush Maximum number of iterations for the foreach will be 250.

Comment: @crush The other file is reading the value once every 2s and is also closing the session after that. This same structure is working in another script but with a `while`. And it was working as is before the server changed.

Comment: @Sergiold Okay, well you shouldn't run into a deadlock or very bad lock-contention with that, I wouldn't think. I'd try extending the script execution timeout, and see if you run into a different error, or no error at all.

Comment: @crush I'll try that but i don't get how can `$_SESSION['numItems']++;` be called more times than the number of `$items`! Thank you!

Comment: I'm just wondering why the script is timing out, and by extending the timeout period, we might find out. It could be that it's having a hard time loading the session into memory every time? Are these sessions really large? Right now, all we know is that the script is taking too long to execute.

Comment: @crush Just tested the code with `set_time_limit(90)` and doesn't help at all. It just gives the same error (after waiting longer) and `$_SESSION['numItems']` ends with a higher value (around 21000).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `session_start` and `session_write_close` again and again

```
session_start();

$items=$_SESSION['items'];
$_SESSION['numItems']=0;

foreach($items as $num => $currentItem){
   $_SESSION['numItems']++;
}

unset($_SESSION['numItems']);
session_write_close();
```

Comment: The code is like that because this way while the foreach is running I can read $_SESSION['numItems'] from another file so the user has real time information of the long execution process. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The basic usage for session would be: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Removing all session_start() and session_write_close() after the first session_start should solve your problem.

Comment: The code is like that because this way while the foreach is running I can read $_SESSION['numItems'] from another file so the user has real time information of the long execution process. Thank you!

Comment: Then I would suggest that you store the progress of your long task in the database. Also for tasks that can exceed the php maximum execution time, consider running them asynchronously (using tools like Gearman or others).